# Binding multiple items of data from SQL to label

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2008

How do I bind multiple data items from SQL to a label?

This is my code:

```
    Dim str As String = ("Data Source=PC1; User ID=sa; Password=pwd;Databasfriend")
    Dim con As New SqlConnection(str)
    Dim str1 As String = "SELECT * FROM tbl_course"
    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(str1, con)
    Dim dataset1 As New DataSet()
    da.Fill(dataset1, "course")
    lbl.DataBindings.Add("text", dataset1, "course.Course_Code")
```

it binds only one item of data, I want to bind many items of data in a particular column

Comment: How are you going to bind multiple data values onto a single label?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a string in the SQL statement and bind to that:

```
Dim str1 As String = "SELECT Course_Title + '(' + Course_Code + ')' AS lbl1 FROM tbl_course"
```

..

```
lbl.DataBindings.Add("text", dataset1, "course.lbl1")
```

Comment: An error occurCannot bind to the property or column lbl1 on the DataSource.
Parameter name: dataMember

Comment: I meant that I edited my answer. Let me know if the new version still has the error.